# How to change background color on mouseenter for the HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sapui5

How to change background color on mouseenter for the  HTML element which is being hover using css class.Same css class has been added to multiple HTML element. 
When its hover the mouse on html element it's changes the background color for all the HTML element which is having same css class added.

Note: I can not add `#id`.

HTML:

```
<div class="customBackgroundForTouch">
<p  > Welcome to Javatpoint.com, Here you get tutorials on latest technologies.</p>  
<p>This is second paragraph</p>  
</div>  

<div class="customBackgroundForTouch">
<p  > Welcome to Javatpoint.com, Here you get tutorials on latest technologies.</p>  
<p>This is second paragraph</p>  
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
<script>        
    $(".customBackgroundForTouch").addEventListener("mouseenter", function(){ 
      $(".customBackgroundForTouch").css({"background-color": "#F5F5DC"});          
    });

    $(".customBackgroundForTouch").addEventListener("mouseleave", function(){ 
        $(".customBackgroundForTouch").css({"background-color": "inherit"});
    });
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.customBackgroundForTouch{
    background-color:inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you don't need `jQuery` to solve it. You don't even need `JavaScript`...

Only **css** solution:

```css
.customBackgroundForTouch:hover {
  background-color: #F5F5DC;
}
```

```html
<div class="customBackgroundForTouch">
  <p> Welcome to Javatpoint.com, Here you get tutorials on latest technologies.</p>
  <p>This is second paragraph</p>
</div>

<div class="customBackgroundForTouch">
  <p> Welcome to Javatpoint.com, Here you get tutorials on latest technologies.</p>
  <p>This is second paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Pure JS solution:

```js
var cls = document.getElementsByClassName('customBackgroundForTouch');
Array.from(cls).forEach(function(v) {
  v.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
    this.style.background = "#F5F5DC";
  });
  v.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
    this.style.background = "inherit";
  });
});
```

```css
.customBackgroundForTouch {
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="customBackgroundForTouch">
  <p> Welcome to Javatpoint.com, Here you get tutorials on latest technologies.</p>
  <p>This is second paragraph</p>
</div>

<div class="customBackgroundForTouch">
  <p> Welcome to Javatpoint.com, Here you get tutorials on latest technologies.</p>
  <p>This is second paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use only CSS follow below code

```css
.customBackgroundForTouch:hover{
    background-color:#F5F5DC;

}
```

```html
<div class="customBackgroundForTouch">
<p  > Welcome to Javatpoint.com, Here you get tutorials on latest technologies.</p>  
<p>This is second paragraph</p>  
</div>  

<div class="customBackgroundForTouch">
<p  > Welcome to Javatpoint.com, Here you get tutorials on latest technologies.</p>  
<p>This is second paragraph</p>  
</div>
```

Using Jquery

```js
        $(".customBackgroundForTouch").on("mouseenter", function(){
        $(this).css({"background-color": "#F5F5DC"});
        })
        
        $(".customBackgroundForTouch").on("mouseleave", function(){
        $(this).css({"background-color": "inherit"});
        })
```

```css
.customBackgroundForTouch{
    background-color:inherit;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="customBackgroundForTouch">
<p  > Welcome to Javatpoint.com, Here you get tutorials on latest technologies.</p>  
<p>This is second paragraph</p>  
</div>  

<div class="customBackgroundForTouch">
<p  > Welcome to Javatpoint.com, Here you get tutorials on latest technologies.</p>  
<p>This is second paragraph</p>  
</div>
```